# Act on Clicked Element in Callback Function

Tags: jquery, dom-traversal

I'm writing some JS functions to handle an element click and process the JSON response. The issue I'm having is referencing the clicked element outside of the click function.

HTML mockup:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="link">
    <a href="#" onclick="linkify()">Test</a>
  </div>
  <div class="output">
    <textarea class="output-textarea"></textarea>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="link">
    <a href="#" onclick="linkify()">Test</a>
  </div>
  <div class="output">
    <textarea class="output-textarea"></textarea>
  </div>
</div>
```

And the JS:

```
// link function
function linkify() {
    // save reference to click element
    activeElement = $(this);
    // make AJAX call
}

// callback function; the parameters of this function 
// are defined by an API and cannot be changed
function callback(json) {
    $(activeElement).closest('.container').find('.output-textarea').val(json);
}
```

jsFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/Lqaw05j8/4/

In my fiddle, the event fires with all variables defined, but my jQuery DOM traversal doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass `this` as an argument to the function:

```
<a href="#" onclick="linkify(this)">Test</a>

function linkify(element) {
    // save reference to click element
    activeElement = element;
    // make AJAX call
}
```

Note that using a global variable like this is not the best way to pass the context to the callback. If the user clicks on another element before the callback fires, it will change the active element. Consider using the `context:` option to `$.ajax()` to pass the context, or make the callback function a closure.

Comment: Both the AJAX call and callback are hardcoded in the API and can't be changed, so this is my attempt to work around the limitation. Is there a better way to do this without changing the AJAX call or the parameters of the callback?

Comment: if you don't pass the parameter, there's no way for `linkify()` to know what element was clicked on. Some browsers have a global variable `event`, so `event.target` will work, but I don't think this works in Firefox.